# How can I maximize the number of valid indices in the given array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am given two arrays "a" and "b" of same size.

Say, array "a":{1,5,6,3,2}

Say, array "b":{2,4,3,2,0}

An index "i" is called "valid" if a[i]>=b[i] .

Our task is to maximize the number of valid indices in the given array "a" and return the final number of valid indices.

We are allowed to do only the following operation on the array "a"(any number of times) :

1)For any 2,indices, 'i' and 'j', swap a[i] with a[j].

2)No changes are allowed to made to the array-'b'.

Solution to the above problem : Swap a[0] with a[4] and we get "5" valid indices.

You can swap any number of times, task is to just maximize the number of valid indices.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I am in need of theoretical help , like what approach should I follow ?

Comment: It is not that easy to explain this on Stackoverflow. Maybe you should consult with someone who can explain you better through physical appearance.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Thanks for your immense help. Have a great day

Comment: I don't think I was helpful at any point :)

Comment: Are you trying to minimize the number of swaps? Or is it ok to maximize the number of valid indices with any number of swaps?

Comment: @user3386109 We are allowed to do infinite number of swaps.

Comment: @user3386109 My greedy algorithm is the same as yours , it just starts with the largest element of 'b' :-)  Thanks, problem solved!

Comment: @AnanyaAgarwal was "problem solved" sarcastic or was it really solved ? If it was solved, would you mind providing the answer ?

Comment: Could you share the link to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm I came up with

- identify `x`: the biggest element in `b`
- if `x` is bigger than all elements in `a`, 
  then pair it with the smallest element of `a`,
  otherwise pair it with the smallest element in `a` that is not smaller than `x`.
- resume search with remaining elements until there are no more elements left to pair
- return number of pairs satisfying a[i]>=b[i]

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts (not tested):

- Sort the array `a`.
- For each element in `b`, do a binary search to find the nearest bigger element for the current `b[i]` in `a`. Once found, remove them from the list. You can use a data structure for this to improve removal or have a boolean array to avoid taken elements.

For the sample input:

```
"a":{1,5,6,3,2}

"b":{2,4,3,2,0}
```

The sorted `a` would be:

```
1 2 3 5 6
```

So by going with nearest largest element strategy, we get `5` as the answer by the arrangement,

```
 "b":{2,4,3,2,0} 
 "a":{2,5,6,3,1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the greedy algorithm.
In the unmarked nums, find the max and min of a, like a[m] and a[n], and find the max of b, b[i]. If a[m] >= b[i]; valid++ and swap a[m] and a[i], else swap a[n] and a[i]. After that, Mark a[i] and b[i].
Loop this until all marked.